# Find all subsets of an array with sum 0

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm given an array of size upto `10^5` (call it n) containing integers. I have to find number to pairs `(i,j), i < j` such that `a_i+...+a_j = 0`.

My attempt:

Clearly the algo should not take more than `nlogn`. I wrote an `n^2` algo that goes as:

1. For all i, find sum of all elements before it (`sum[i][0]`) and after it (`sum[i][1]`). This will take `O(n)` time.
2. Call sum of all elements tSum.
3. For any `(i,j)` I can find the required in sum in `O(1)` time using `tSum - sum[j][1] - sum[i][0]`.

Since possible no of such `(i,j)` is of order `n^2`, it will take me `O(n^2)` time. I tried, but was unable to reduce it down to `O(n) or O(nlogn)`. Please give me some hints on how this could be done. Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `S` be the array:

```
S[i] = a_0 + ... + a_i-1
```

Then,

```
S[j+1] - S[i] = a_j + ... + a_i
```

You want to find the pairs `i < j` having `S[i] == S[j+1]`.

In `O(n lg n)`: just sort `S` (on values, but keep the indices) and check for consecutives values that are identic.

In amortized `O(n)`: create a hash map `x -> [all i with S[i] == x]` and output the combinations if there are two elements or more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n log n) or even O(n).

Create empty set of pairs (number, number of its occurrences) S (BST - O(n log n), hash array - expected O(n))

For each i from 1 to n (where n is the length of the array):

- Calculate prefix sum. (prefsum[i] = prefsum[i-1] + array[i]) Let's call it x.
- Find number of x in a set S. Add it to the result (if you had previously a prefix sum with sum x, you can substract it from you current prefix sum and get a subarray with sum equal to 0)
- Add/increase amount of x in S

Answer (score 1):

Instead of step 3, you can create a dictionary keyed by `tSum - sum[j][1]` and with value of `j`, you do this for all elements and go through the array again checking for the presence of `sum[i][0]` in the dictionary, if it is there you can output the pair `i, j`.